# Call Sub Shema to validate different property in Json Schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I am preparing JSON schema to validate my data. However, unable to do certain thing what I am looking.

```
My Data:
{
    "orderName": "CoreCapital",
    "orderType": "Capital",
    "requestId": "Generated ID",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "User",
            "taskId": 1,
            "name": "Level-1",
            "executor": "Marine",
            "description": "Get Details",
            "properties": {
                "stateId": 123,
                "params": [
                    "parameter1",
                    "parameter2"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Manager",
            "taskId": 2,
            "name": "Lavel-2",
            "executor": "Shipping",
            "description": "Shipping Details",
            "properties": {
                "id": 2345,
                "baseId": "Shipping-23",
                "method": "POST",
                "params": {
                    "Id": "1234",
                    "tag": "Fire"
                },
                "locale": {
                    "USA": "tag-1",
                    "Canada": "tag-2",
                    "Europe": "tag-3"
                }
        },
        {
            "type": "Director",
            "taskId": 3,
            "name": "Lavel-3",
            "executor": "Transport",
            "description": "Transport Details",,
            "properties": {
                "name" : "Water-resource"
                "payload": "truck details",
                "Size": "40 ton",
                "State": {
                    "CA": "tag-4",
                    "AR": "tag-5",
                    "MS": "tag-6"
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    ],

}
```

I want to validate each task in a different way, if the task type is User it will have different properties, if it is Manager, it will have different properties. I want to group the common attributes into one schema and then create different schemas for properties in each task.

Below is the pseudo code of the main schema

```
if type ="User"
   properties = $ref : #/definitions/UserProperties
if type ="Manager"
    properties = $ref : #/definitions/ManagerProperties
if type ="Director"
    properties = $ref : #/definitions/DirectorProperties
```

all these definitions of sub schema I defined. But the validator is not validating the subschema.

each subschema will validate what attribute is required or not.

Any Idea how to call based on task type value? if the type is user, then validate the user schema, if the type is manager, then validate the manager schema like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if, then` syntax in JSON Schema draft-07 or later on your `properties` property in the `tasks` array.

I've defined a basic `taskType` with the shared properties and individual schemas for each `type`. (User, Manager, Director)

The `if, then` syntax is used in the `taskType` schema where it checks the value of `type` and defines the proper schema. We use `allOf` because we have multiple `if, then` conditions to validate. If a defined `type` is identified, the proper schema is applied. If no `type` is identified, there are no constraints defined on the `properties`, thus, anything would be valid.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "orderName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "orderType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "requestId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tasks": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/taskType"
            }
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "taskType": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "taskId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "executor": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "properties": {}
            },
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "const": "User"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "properties": {
                            "properties": {
                                "$ref": "#/$defs/UserTask"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "const": "Manager"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "properties": {
                            "properties": {
                                "$ref": "#/$defs/ManagerTask"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "const": "Director"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "properties": {
                            "properties": {
                                "$ref": "#/$defs/DirectorTask"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "UserTask": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "stateId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "params": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "uniqueItems": true,
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "ManagerTask": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "baseId": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "method": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "params": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Id": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "tag": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "locale": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "propertyNames": {
                        "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
                    },
                    "patternProperties": {
                        "": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "DirectorTask": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "payload": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Size": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "State": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "propertyNames": {
                        "pattern": "^[A-Z]{2}$"
                    },
                    "patternProperties": {
                        "": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

```json
{
  "orderName": "CoreCapital",
  "orderType": "Capital",
  "requestId": "Generated ID",
  "tasks": [
      {
          "type": "User",
          "taskId": 1,
          "name": "Level-1",
          "executor": "Marine",
          "description": "Get Details",
          "properties": {
              "stateId": 123,
              "params": [
                  "parameter1",
                  "parameter2"
              ]
          }
      },
      {
          "type": "Manager",
          "taskId": 2,
          "name": "Lavel-2",
          "executor": "Shipping",
          "description": "Shipping Details",
          "properties": {
              "id": 2345,
              "baseId": "Shipping-23",
              "method": "POST",
              "params": {
                  "Id": "1234",
                  "tag": "Fire"
              },
              "locale": {
                  "USA": "tag-1",
                  "Canada": "tag-2",
                  "Europe": "tag-3"
              }
            }
      },
      {
          "type": "Director",
          "taskId": 3,
          "name": "Lavel-3",
          "executor": "Transport",
          "description": "Transport Details",
          "properties": {
              "name" : "Water-resource",
              "payload": "truck details",
              "Size": "40 ton",
              "State": {
                  "CA": "tag-4",
                  "AR": "tag-5",
                  "MS": "tag-6"
              }
          }
          
      }
      
  ]

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you...it works fine now.. The issue was that I was adding only one properties. Below code works perfectly.

 "then": {
                        "properties": {
                            "properties": {
                                "$ref": "#/$defs/UserTask"
                            }
                        }
                    }

Comment: It's tricky when your schema is using some of the reserved JSON Schema keywords as regular property names. It can be confusing. Glad you resolved it.